# Li Problems with formatting text Please help?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I have a dropdown menu which at at the minute has a different coloured title above different sections in the menu e.g

Title (colour1)

option1 (colour2)

**(Above and below)**

I would like to change it so that on the list it looks is as follows (two colours on one line):

Title (colour1) Option1 (colour 2)

**(Side by side)**

I asked a question earlier about how to fix this and got an answer. However the list items still go above and below rather than side by side.

the css looks like this:

```
#drop {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:inherit;
    left: 183px;
    width:700px;
    top: 15px;
    }

#drop ul {
    background: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;      
    }

#drop ul li {
    width: 750px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;      
    margin: 0 10px -10 0;
    }

#drop ul li span {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;      
    padding: 1px 3px;
    }

#drop ul li ul {
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    list-style-type: none;      
    display: none; 
    padding: 0 0em 0.5em 0;
    }

#drop ul li:hover ul {
    list-style-type: none;      
    opacity: 0.9;
    }

#drop ul li ul li {
    border: none;       
    list-style-type: none;  
    float: none;
    padding-left:0px;
    }

#drop ul li ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #808285;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    }


#drop ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: #d8d8dc;
    }


#drop ul li.section-title SPAN.section-title {
    color:#434442;
    margin-left: -3px;
    }

span.nav-title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808285;   
    position:fixed;
    left: 223px;
    width:744px;
    top: 28px;
    cursor:pointer;

    }
```

And the Html like this:

```
<div id="dropbox"></div>
                    <div id="Dropp style="position:relative;z-index:1000">
<div id="drop" style="position:absolute;z-index:3000">
    <ul>
        <li id="dropbox"><span class="nav-title" style="z-index:3000">Deutsche Börse Photography Prize 2011</span> <div class="nav-title" id="triangle">
                    </div>
            <ul id="ddd" class="subnav" style:"display: none;" >
                <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <li>—</li>
            <li class="section-title">
                <span class="section-title">Photographers Gallery</span>
            </li>
                <li><a href="Deutsche Börse Photography Prize 2011.html">Deutsche Börse Photography Prize 2011</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deutsche Börse Photography Prize 2010</a></li>
```

**And there is an example of it in use here:**
www.deanpauley.co.uk/O-SB/categories.html

The advice I was given was to change it to:

```
<ul>
    <li class="section"><span class="title">Title 1</span><span class="content">Color 2</span></li>
    <li class="section"><span class="title">Title 1</span><span class="content">Color 2</span></li>
    <li class="section"><span class="title">Title 1</span><span class="content">Color 2</span></li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help? Is it to do with the padding/margins that the text wont go on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you mean but it will achieve what I think you want!

```
<ul>
    <li class="section" style="overflow:hidden">
        <span class="title" style="display:block; float:left; width:somewidth">Title Color 1</span>                        
        <ul class="content" style="width:somewidth; float:left">
            <li>Content Color 2</li>
            <li>Content Color 2</li>
            <li>Content Color 2</li>
            <li>Content Color 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Excuse the inline styles, but i'm lazy this afternoon :)

That will result in:

Title Color 1 --> 
Content Colour 2
                ->***_*__*_*__*_*___** Content Colour 2
               ->**__*_*__*_*__*_*__**  Content Colour 2
               ->***_*__*_*__*_*____**  Content Colour 2

Replace 'somewidth' with the widths you require - will keep it more uniform and less buggy than using auto widths. But you could use auto widths and add styling for ie6 - which wont play ball!

Comment: sorry I couldnt format the output properly! but you get the idea!